# HTML5 Video pause and rewind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Is there any way to pause and rewind to 0s a HTML5 video? Or just simply stop?

I got a jQuery popup, so when someone clicks on it, the popup shows up and the video plays, and when you hit the close button the video pauses. So what I'm trying to do is that if you click again the button to show the popup the video begins in the start position (0 secs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can get a reference to your jquery video element upon opening it (or closing the popup) and pause it using pause(), and then set the "currentTime" property to 0 to go back to the beginning.

Here's a reference to the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#dom-media-currenttime) for currentTime.

here's a code sample:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("video"); 
mediaElement.pause(); 
mediaElement.currentTime = 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all:

document.getElementById('video') {
  this.currentTime = 0;
}

What am I doing wrong? Any jQuery option?

Comment: @AlejandroAr try this if your video tag id is 'video'. 
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("video");  
mediaElement.pause();
mediaElement.currentTime = 0;

Comment: @AlejandroAr With jquery, you can do $('#videoId').get(0).pause(); $('#videoId').get(0).currentTime = 0;

Comment: Or just $("video").get(0) if you don't have an id and have only one video player (the most common option).

Answer (score 9):

To have a proper `stop` (pause & rewind) functionality you could do the following:

```
var video = document.getElementById('vidId');
// or video = $('.video-selector')[0];
video.pause();
video.currentTime = 0;
video.load();
```

Note: This is the only version that worked for me in chrome using `nodejs` (`meteorjs`) in the backend, serving `webm` & `ogg` files

Comment: `video.load(); video.play();`
I couldn't get this to work without load.  I think the API has changed.

Answer (score 6):

Just call the `pause()` method of the video element. To reset the time, set `currentTime` to 0 (or any other value if needed, in seconds).

Answer (score 2):

To reset a video to 0 seconds in [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
$('#video')[0].currentTime = 0;
```

Or, in vanilla JS (Although this has been pointed out above):

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.currentTime = 0;
```