# Is it possible to embed actions in html5 video?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to play a video in html5, stop and execute javascript at known points within the video?

Comment: You mean the way Youtube does it right?

Comment: Everything is possible!

Comment: btw what do you mean by within the video?

Comment: Posted an answer for you that i think you find useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try this. You have to use the currentTime property. Start with that and start your javascript functions from there. Is that what you're looking for?

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video");

//Add a timeupdate listener
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    //Check for video properties from within the function
    if (this.currentTime == 5)
        this.pause();
        //cal javascript
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the accepted answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853594/html5-video-pause-and-rewind) it looks like it is possible.

To pause the video you just do this:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("video"); // create a reference to your HTML5 video
mediaElement.pause(); // pauses the video
```

If you want to play the video, do this:

```
mediaElement.play(); // plays the video
```

To get the current time in the video, do this:

```
mediaElement.currentTime; // gets the current time
```

Here's an example linking them all up:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("video");
if(mediaElement.currentTime == 35){
    mediaElement.pause();
    // do whatever else you would like
    mediaElement.play();
}
```

The MDL documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), there are plenty of other properties you might find helpful.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by doing like this you can.

Note that you have to look for a time using bigger than `>` bigger than (as the chance to match an exact millisecond is almost zero), and have a variable in one way or the other to know which ones is done.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var cur = document.querySelector('#cur'),
      vid = document.querySelector('#vid')
})

var appDone = {"done7":false,"done4":false}

vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
  if (e.target.currentTime > 7 && !appDone.done7) {
    appDone.done7 = true;
    e.target.pause();
    //do something
    cur.textContent += ", " + "done7 once";
    
    e.target.play();
  }
  if (e.target.currentTime > 4 && !appDone.done4) {
    appDone.done4 = true;
    e.target.pause();
    //do something
    cur.textContent += ", " + "done4 once";
    
    e.target.play();      
  }
})
```

```html
<video id="vid" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p id="cur"></p>
```