# How can i rewind a video to the start with a double click on a button and display a poster image when the video is paused

Tags: javascript

// this function resets the video to the beginning.

```
function resetVideoToStart(video){

  if (myVideo.currentTime <=0){
    stopVideo();
    myVideo.load();
    scrubVideo();
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video pause and rewind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853594/html5-video-pause-and-rewind)

Comment: I have implemented that into my code but the problem I am having is setting the poster image at the start of the video when i have double click the button to rewind it to the start.